# Is SO's programmers site a better place for advanced questions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Two questions I asked received some downvotes on Stack Overflow.

1. Has anyone encountered random script errors on comment lines in IE8?
2. Does object literal notation containing functions execute faster than plain functions?

Question one is not a poll, it asks if this is a known problem.  Question two is a question about code performance that has a technical answer not open to debate, I just don't know it.

Questions I would not ask on SO:

3) Is a verbose programming style an issue when compression, minification and obfuscation are available?
4) Can someone provide a list of available obfuscation tools?

Those involve opinion, discussion, and (as I just learned) lists. Would these questions also be voted down or rejected on Programmers.stackexchange.com or is that a more appropriate venue?

Related to this, is Programmers  the appropriate place for subjective and discussion oriented questions instead of using Stack Overflow?

Comment: Question one is a poll.  SO is not a mechanism for confirming bugs by polling its participants.  The right question to ask (in general terms) is "what is causing this error and how can I fix it?"

Comment: No, Programmers is not a place for discussion-style subjective questions either.

Comment: Question one is certainly a poll.  It's also a terrible question, even if it's not a poll.  Ask what you really want: "I'm encountering random-seeming errors like so; why?".

Comment: I'd add that nowhere on StackExchange is intended to be a location for discussion, subjective questions, or really anything along those lines.  All SE sites share in common the fact that they are intended to be question-and-answer format where a single question has a single answer (perhaps many single answers, but each are in their own right a complete answer to the question).  Chat rooms are perhaps the best places to ask discussion questions like this; we have plenty of chat rooms here so you can freely do so.

Comment: @DHorse: as I told you in a comment on your other post, question 2 *has* an answer, and it was posted as a comment on that question: it makes no difference at all. It doesn't matter how an object is created: it ends up being the same object.

Comment: Your question two has been discussed extensively, both here and on the question itself.  The consensus seems to be that it is not a particularly advanced question, nor is it especially difficult to answer; all you need is a code profiler and some test code.

Comment: As to the question at hand, the differences between Programmers and Stack Overflow have very little to do with the relative difficulty level of the question.  The differences have more to do with question scope: Programmers is for conceptual questions, SO is for code questions.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Yes thank you, your answer (comment) was useful and I up voted it.  My question was regarding functions of global scope and a brief answer is posted on that thread.  It was still a bad question on my part though.  I was looking to determine the cause of the negative votes, which I thought might be either the answer was of little use or the question would invoke too much discussion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would agree with both "not a particularly advanced question, nor is it especially difficult to answer."  I did not realize my poor choice of wording was the problem on the SO site and why my initial search results were so poor.  I was attempting to be specific, not confusing.  This also explains the down voting and lack of answer.  Thanks

Comment: @RobertHarvey re:"Question one is a poll." Because I originally did not expect my code to be debugged I ended up phrasing it that way.  It would have been better stated "Is there a bug in IE8 that generates random errors on comment lines?".  I expected an answer of the form "Yes, other people have that problem" or "No it never happens."  Being new, at the time I thought "Ok, this the way to ask the question, I am not conducting a poll."  Yes, it is a polling question regardless of the intent.  The answer effected my strategy for fixing it.

Comment: Those are hardly "advanced" questions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Only the IE8 question.  The object literal notation question re dereferencing is either intermediate or advanced depending on how much detail on the JS engine is provided (the answer might be advanced).

Comment: BTW the object literal notation answer I got on the non-duplicate thread/post was very straight forward (not advanced) and probably better for it.

Comment: I do think that deferencing is something a programmer should study from the very beginning.  However, I also think that only advanced programmers should answer questions of that sort.  In other forums, answers to questions (I.E. C# and the merits of CLR) have been very in depth and I think beyond novice programmers.  With that said, they should also be required study material.  Dunno.

Comment: The IE8 question is advanced in that the usual good techniques currently (see the comments) are problematic.  While requiring a great deal of time they are unlikely to identify the problem because they change (and break) the code too much.  Changes will likely make the problem disappear but not identify the actual cause.  It thus becomes an issue of finding the problem in the code AS IS.  I provided an update that might do that.  Someone reporting it as an existing problem or not isn't advance but helps with strategy.  They might have detailed knowledge of the fault in IE8 (advanced?)

Comment: Another IE8 example I haven't added to that post.  It is very odd that IE9 eliminated the problem for me, but someone else has it.  Curious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Programmers and SO have a different scope.  yes, in some cases there is a bit of overlap, but by and large questions pretty clearly belong in one site or another.  It's not a question of expertise or difficulty, it's a question of the topic.

Your first question is a polling question, and polling questions don't belong on the SE network in general.  Going to programmers won't help you with that.

Your second question is on topic for SO, and it's *not* on topic on programmers.  It would probably be closed as offtopic on programmers.  It was poorly received on SO because it was poorly written, not clear what you were asking, etc. (At least based on what I've seen in comments there.)  You should focus on improving the question, not finding a different place to ask it.  Even if that were on topic for programmers, or some other site, quality and clarity is important on *all* SE sites.  The solution to an unclear question is to make it clear, not to move it somewhere else.

> is Programmers the appropriate place for subjective and discussion oriented questions instead of using Stack Overflow?

No.

All sites require *some* level of subjectivity.  It's mostly a question of degree.  Some sites allow a bit more subjectivity than others, and SO falls more on the less subjective side, while Programmers is at least a but further down the scale.  Note that while some subjectivity is expected, *discussion* isn't; posts should still be posted in the Question/Answer format; this isn't a forum.  See [Good subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for an idea as to what types of subjectivity are appropriate and what isn't (for the SE network as a whole).  (Note that blog post is rather old; it's comments about what the scope of Programmers is is very out of date, even though the concept of appropriate levels of subjectiveness are still valid.)

Comment: I wouldn't claim P.SE isn't actually further down the subjectivity scale than SO; in my experiences it's really spot on the same as far as it's tolerance for subjectivity. But that's just my analysis of what I've seen on P.SE

Comment: This is has been very helpful, thanks.  If a question sounds like a poll, it is a poll.  Poor wording appears to consistently be my issues where my four questions were concerned.

Answer (score 12):

I believe the first question you're referring to is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183521/expected-and-syntax-error-on-comment-lines-along-with-object-expected-errors) (now deleted). I don't think it was downvoted so much for the technical content as it was due to the text that was in [the original version you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/a318ef12-8ca3-435c-938f-7f867a935973/view-source):

> I CAN'T POST BECAUSE EDITOR CLAIMS I HAVE CODE AT AN UNDISCLOSED
>   LOCATION...  ANY HELP?
>
> I CAN'T POST BECAUSE EDITOR CLAIMS I HAVE CODE AT AN UNDISCLOSED
>   LOCATION...  ANY HELP?
>
> I CAN'T POST BECAUSE EDITOR CLAIMS I HAVE CODE AT AN UNDISCLOSED
>   LOCATION...  ANY HELP?
>
> I CAN'T POST BECAUSE EDITOR CLAIMS I HAVE CODE AT AN UNDISCLOSED
>   LOCATION...  ANY HELP?
>
> I CAN'T POST BECAUSE EDITOR CLAIMS I HAVE CODE AT AN UNDISCLOSED
>   LOCATION...  ANY HELP?
>
> Would someone mind telling me what the problem is in the following
>   text...  Thank you.  Where is the code in the following text?

That had nothing to do with the question, and was a complaint about the posting system. People reacted negatively to that.

Your [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653474/does-object-literal-notation-containing-functions-execute-faster-than-plain-func#question) was downvoted and closed because the original version of it lacked detail and was somewhat vague. Your clarifying edits afterward helped, which is why I and a few others voted to reopen it, but I am a little concerned that you recently stripped out all that detail once again.

Your other questions seem fairly reasonable, so I don't think it's their subject matter that people are responding badly to.

Comment: Hmmm, I stripped it out after being told that the detail was a major issue.  I'll put it back in.  I did get an answer.  I think I was really asking "Are functions in an object slower than plain functions?"  The issue of object literal notation being one of style and not relevant.  I think.

Comment: Ok I put the detail back.  This pretty well confirms that no matter what I did I would get down votes and therefore blocked.  It is a standard question to ask in other languages. C# and the CLR for example, where the answer is surprisingly no, not much.  The answer where JavaScript isn't really debatable and is quantifiable.  I'll answer my own question later when I find out.  Thanks for reopening it though.

Comment: Your answer is equally correct to the one above but I can only check one.  It was also the poll like phrasing in the IE8 question.  It should have read "Is there a bug in IE8 that causes pseudo random errors on comment lines?" Little or lots of detail could both result in down votes but that was a bad choice of words, it was a poll. I did find one possible answer now missing from the closed post.  I will eventually return to the old code and post the answer on the P.SE site.  Thanks.